# How to make a scar selection adjust based on underlying skin color

Tags: adobe-photoshop, creative-cloud

So in the vanilla game that I am trying to mod there is selection of scars that are very pinkish and do not adjust based on the skin color you select for your character. From my research, scars are actually a shade of your skin color and can range from very light (I have very light skin and almost white scars) to pretty dark. I should mention that you can have 10 different shades of skin in the game.

The color map is saved as an RGBA and looks like this (the brown is an alpha channel):
[image: RGBA color map of scar]

Now what I want is to basically make the selection of the scar translucent. I figured I would do this by changing the opacity of the selection but can't quite figure out how to do this.

Before that I tried to make the scar just lighter but quickly realized that it looks pretty bad on dark skin. There just does not seem to be a setting where I can adjust the opacity. At least I don't see it anywhere.